# For the Conjure Fey spell, who chooses the CR, whether it's a beast or fey, and the actual creature - the player, or the DM?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, summoning

The description of the [*conjure fey*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-fey) spell says (emphasis mine):

> You summon a **fey creature** of challenge rating 6 or lower, **or a fey spirit that takes the form of a beast** of challenge rating 6 or lower.

I would like to know what the player actually gets to choose:

- Does the player choose the CR, whether it is a beast or a fey, and
  the creature?
- Does the the player choose the CR and whether it is a beast or a fey,
  while the DM chooses the actual creature that appears?
- Or does the player only choose the CR, while the DM chooses the
  creature and whether it is a beast or a fey?

Comment: Related: [How to decide what creatures are summoned?](/questions/108743/), [How do you determine which beast appears during the Conjure Animals spell?](/questions/71346/), [Does Conjure Minor Elementals let the caster choose which elemental to summon?](/questions/137508/)

Comment: Hi MikeQ! Thanks for the related threads! I saw some of these, but Conjure Fey seems to work a bit differently than the ones described in the sage advice, as they all give a creature type while Conjure Fey gives two. My main question is whether or not Conjure Fey allows the player to choose between the two creature types or if the DM does.

Answer (score 5):

### The DM chooses everything

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) deals with this in the question "When you cast a spell like conjure woodland beings, does the spellcaster or the DM choose the creatures that are conjured?" (p. 16).

It states that "Some spells of this sort specify that the spellcaster chooses the creature conjured" and gives [Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) as an example ("an animal form **you** choose"). And also "Other spells of this sort let the spellcaster choose from among several broad options" giving [Conjure Minor Elementals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-minor-elementals) as an example ("**You** choose one the following options for what appears").

The spell description is explicit in what elements the caster can choose. If it is silent, the choice falls to the DM.

For [Conjure Fey](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-fey) the description gives no choices to the player, therefore everything is up to the DM.